# WCF client authentication scheme 'Basic'. to a java server

Tags: wcf, soapui

I'm trying to consume a java web service using basic authentication.

Using Soap UI I can receive a response when running a  request with basic authentication.

The problem is using VS studio  i'm having this error using basic authentification

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm='weblogic'

`enter code here`

```html
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Comment: Is the client using C#? IS it possible that simply the credentials are incorrect?

Comment: What credentials did you provide in SoapUI? Did you include the realm?

Comment: I'm passing the same credentials used in Soap ui , I dont pass the realm the Client is in C#

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, sir. This is the exact error we're running into. Many kudos if you could share.

Answer (score 0):

Your transport configuration specifies an empty realm while the server users `weblogic`. Try adding the same realm you used with SoapUI, eg:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="weblogic" />
```

Comment: Hi , I set the realm to weblogic and still have the same issue but I don't use real in Soap UI but it works fine...